# WSO2 API Manager backend url

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have the API manager pointing to a backend with domain and not ip and then there is a DNS entry for the domain. It is not working however but when I do the call myself from the gateway it works fine. What I was wondering is is does the API manager do a dns lookup for the IP of the domain and then use that in the URL for the backend call or does it leave the URL as is. The reason I am asking is that the backend need the domain to route the request to the right API.

Thanks

Comment: It should work with domain name. What is the error you're getting? Do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: There is no error in the api manager and the response I get is from the load balancer which says there is no service to handle the request. Because it is using the domain name to route.

Comment: If you are sure it is using the domain name then maybe the issue is somewhere else I just wanted to check it does use the domain name

Comment: Yes, this should be some loadbalancer config issue. You can enable `wire` logs in APIM by putting below line to log4j.properties file, and see how request goes... 
`log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG`

Comment: Thx for the help :)

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: posted as an answer. what really was the issue? loadbalancer config issue?

Comment: Yeah the LB is listening on port 80 but it appears that the API manager is adding the port on to the end of the domain and for some reason that isn't working on the LB so will get out platforms guys to have a look. Thx for the help the debug pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with domain name. API Manager uses the backend URL as it is (and append resources to that URL) to send requests to backend. So, in your case most probably it should be a loadbalancer configuration issue.